# How to have multiple if cases in a condition statement in Ant

Tags: if-statement, ant, conditional-statements

Like in a switch statement, I want to set different values in the different cases

I can have only one condition and set only two different values in this conditional statement:

```
<condition property="prop" value="1" else="2">
   <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="one"/>
</condition>
```

And once set, the `prop` is immutable so I can't change its value.

What I need is something like this

```
if (param1 == "one") {
   prop = 1;
} else if (param1 == "two") {
   prop = 2;
} else if (param1 == "three") {
   prop = 3;
} ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use separate conditions and rely on the fact that properties are immutable

```
<condition property="prop" value="1">
     <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="one"/>
</condition>
<condition property="prop" value="2">
    <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="two"/>
</condition>
...
```

and add a regular property for the final else

```
<property name="prop" value="else">
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! With immutable properties the code logic gets a bit unusual but I'll get used to it.